# Serve the contact form with fields already filled out depending on what was clicked to get you there

Tags: php, html, button, contact-form

I'm trying to set up a website that has a list of products. Under each product is a button that says "Request a Quote".
When they click that button, I want them to be taken to the contact page with the subject line filled out with the product ID and a predetermined string (i.e. "Quote Request").

How can I set up the "Request a quote button" to send the data and get the subject line in the contact page to read it?

I'm sorry if it's an obvious one, I'm pretty new at this and I'm doing this as a for-learning project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with appending the subject into the GET string.

```
   contact.php?subject=thus+is+the+subject
```

Then on the contact page you can get it with `$_GET['subject']`;

```
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['subject'];  ?>" />
```

Comment: But do I just type this into the HTML page or is this part of a PHP document?  (Remember, I'm only a couple months into this :)

Comment: @Imray they are on and the same. In your html page that should have the extension `.php` you use this in your html, it includes PHP tags

Comment: "they are on and the same."?

Comment: @Imray the html page and the php page. Your file should have the .php extension, display the HTML regularly and in the form input element open up the PHP tags like I have shown.

Comment: Both my files (the page with the products and the contact page) are in HTML. The only PHP file I have is a simple file with the code to send the email from the contact form.

Comment: @Imray so change the extension of your html files to `.php`. HTML runs on PHP files as well. Then this code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps : 
http://www.phpriot.com/articles/multi-step-wizards

You need to pass the parameters by GET or POST method to your contact form first, then catch them in contact.php and then display them as @InGodITrust said. 
In other ways, you mat use some Wizard Controls or you can do it yourself!